# How to define a "recommended" path for pedestrian

Tags: anylogic

I am looking for a way to move pedestrian by given target location and a nonmandatory path. Let pedestrian decides when and where to start walking on the path depends on the initial location of pedestrian.

I tried using the option "Follow Route", but it forces pedestrian start from beginning of the path even the location of beginning is on opposite direction of final target location. That results more travel distance than I expected.
Let's say the path consisted of 3 points A->B->C. The initial location of pedestrian is near B and target location is C. I expect the pedestrian enters the path at B instead of the beginning A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use the direct movement (which would be from B->C in your example) or you position pathways cleverly and send your peds to the correct one with manual logic and flow-chart branches.

i.e. a ped checks "oh, I am near B, I should not take the A-B-C pathway and logic, I should take the separate B-C pathway and logic"

But that is for you to model explicitly